# Sympy returns a ConditionSet object when solving an equation, while matlab returns a single float when the same equation is solved

Tags: python, matlab, sympy

I have 4 input variables (floats):

Xmax
Xmin
percentage
mode
and I want to solve the following (rather long) equation for s:

```
> (1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmax)-(log(mode)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s))-(1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmin)-(log(mode)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s))) - percentage == 0
```

I want to use sympy to solve the equation, but it returns a ConditionSet Object (meaning that it cannot solve the equation)

My code is as follows:

```
from sympy import *

def CalcScaleParam(mode, CIfact, percentage):
    s = Symbol('s', Real=True)
    eqn = (1/2+1/2*erf((log(4)-(log(2)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s))-(1/2+1/2*erf((log(1)-(log(2)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s)))) - 0.95
    sigma = solveset(eqn, s)
    print(sigma)

CalcScaleParam(2,2, 0.9545)
```

My Matlab code is as follows:

```
function sigma = Test()

syms s
eqn =(1/2+1/2*erf((log(4)-(log(2)+s^2))/(sqrt(2)*s))-(1/2+1/2*erf((log(1)-(log(2)+s^2))/(sqrt(2)*s)))) - 0.95 == 0;
sigma = solve(eqn,s);

end
```

And returns sigma=0.335

I initially thought it was an issue with the math but since the equation is solved successfully in matlab I suspect that the problem is coming from sympy.

Comment: Judging by the docs, Matlab `solve` without the `ReturnConditions` option set to `true` only tries to find *a* solution. `solveset` tries to find all solutions.

Comment: `solveset` is only going to give symbolic solutions. If you want numerical solutions, use a numerical solver, like `sympy.nsolve` or one of [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).

Comment: Running the same code in matlab with `ReturnConditions` set to true does indeed return `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.` Which I think is what the return of `ConditionSet` in sympy means. I thought that the sympy docs recommend the use of `solveset` in sympy 1.0 instead of other solvers. Using nsolve gives this [error](https://gist.github.com/cachemoi/0aa07e7c5365f4e4bf8e44683c3f36d9) which boils down to mpmath...

Comment: @asmeurer has the correct answer, with fractions correctly defined, `sympy.nsolve(eqn, 0.5)` gives `mpf('0.33558869646266484')`, like your matlab solution.

Comment: The problem with `nsolve` is that you have to give a guess (`0.5`). I really don't understand how matlab is able to come up with a single numerical solution.

Comment: I tried to break my problem in a system of equations and using `linsolve` to find a solution, but it returns an empty set. Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/cachemoi/89e1861559f9d1a0854090651de89858)

Answer (score 1):

The fractions are using Python's integer division, which gives `1/2 == 0`. The entire expression reduces to `-0.95`. Declare it using `1./2` or `0.5`, or maybe Rational(1,2). You might also have to express the percentage 0.95 as `Rational(19,20)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I used all of your proposed combination and it returned the same results. `Solveset` solves the equations correctly when I use fractions in other equations, like **1/2+s**

Comment: I'm not an advanced user, so it could well be that this is not the problem. However, `simplify(eqn)` gives `-0.95` and `solveset(eqn, s)` gives an `EmptySet`, whereas it finds a symbolic solution with the fractions properly defined as `Rational`.

Comment: FYI, when the fractions are correctly defined, it returns the same symbolic solution as Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the Sympy Live Shell, which has `from __future__ import division` executed on launch, or Python 3;  that would be why you don't need to define your fractions explicitly.