# Why can the solve() function in matlab solve this equation while the nsolve() function in sympy requires a guess?

Tags: python, matlab, math, sympy

I have a mode, a maximum and minimum value of X (`Xmin` and `Xmax`), and a percentage confidence (`percentage`).

I want to use the following functions in order to find the μ and σ of a theoretical log normal distribution:

The cumulative distribution function:

[image: CDF]

and the mode

[image: mode]

I began with the following Matlab script:

```
function [mu, sigma] = DefLog(Mode, Percentage, Xmin, Xmax)

syms s
eqn = 1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmax)-(log(Mode)+s^2))/(sqrt(2)*s))-(1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmin)-(log(Mode)+s^2))/(sqrt(2)*s)))==Percentage;
sigma = solve(eqn,s)

mu=log(Mode)+sigma^2

end
```

And this gives me a single numerical solution for mu and sigma.

For example if I run `DefLog(2, 0.95, 1, 4)` I get `sigma = 0.33` and `mu = 0.80`

I needed to translate this equation into Python, so I used `sympy` to solve the same equation. The only way I could get a single numerical solution with sympy was to use the `nsolve` function. My code is as follows:

```
from sympy import *

def CalcScaleParamOPT(mode, percentage, Xmin, Xmax):

    s = Symbol('s', Real=True)

    eqn = (1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmax)-(log(mode)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s))-(1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmin)-(log(mode)+s**2))/(sqrt(2)*s)))) - 0.95

    sigma = nsolve(eqn, 0.6)

    mu=log(mode)+sigma**2

    print(sigma)
    print(mu.evalf())


CalcScaleParamOPT(2, 0.95, 1, 4)
```

This gives the same solution as the matlab script, but unlike the matlab `solve()` function `nsolve()` requires a "guess" close enough to the answer I am looking for. How can matlab find a single solution without the guess?

Comment: Those are two completely different functions. Matlab's `solve` is a symbolic solver (similar to Sympy's `solve`). Sympy's `nsolve` is a numeric solver (similar to Matlab's `vpasolve` or maybe `fsolve`).

Comment: the docs say `solve()` is to be replaced with `solvestet()` in sympy 1.0, but using `solveset` to solve this does not return any results. I am using nsolve following a recommendation I got when I asked about this difference, link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818218/sympy-returns-a-conditionset-object-when-solving-an-equation-while-matlab-retur)

Comment: A guess implies a non-linear, iterative, numerical solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#zmw57dd0e125966), MATLAB's `solve` falls back to a numerical solution automatically. Assumedly it generates a guess value automatically (it doesn't mention how), but it does say that you can use `vpasolve` to pass in a guess interval manually, since the default `solve` only returns one numerical solution (the first one it finds).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that seems to be the case. Do you know of a sympy function that would generate the guess value automatically? I cannot seem to find one in the docs. `nsolve()` fails if the guess value is too far off.

Comment: Looks like `nsolve` also lets you pass in an interval for a guess, if that helps. `nsolve` is just a wrapper around `mpmath.findroot`, so you might look at [its docs](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.findroot) for more information on what it can do.